# Angular 9 - different formGroupName with same name of formControlName affects same formControlName

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms

I created form: FormGroup variable where I defined group with a FormArray localizationData: FormArray like this in constructor of my service:

```
this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
    localizationData: this.formBuilder.array([])
});
```

Then I pushing to that FormArray a FormGroup with specific FormControl with this function:

```
addLocalizedFormGroup(locale?: any){
    locale = (locale == undefined) ? this.selectedLocale : locale;
    let formArray = <FormArray>this.form.get('localizationData');
    formArray.push(this.formBuilder.group({       
        locale: [locale.code],
        codelistName: ['', Validators.required]
    }));
    locale.created = true;
    this.createdLocales.push(locale);
}
```

In ngOnInit of component I called that function twice. Example of locale object variable:

```
{ "code": "SK", "name": "Slovenčina" }
```

To show to user specific format of that locale I using this function:

```
localeFormatter = (x: any) => x.code + " | " + x.name;
```

I implemented simple options list with localizations for user to select one:

```
<div class="form-group col-3">
    <label>Lokalizácia
        <select class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="this.defservice.selectedLocale">
            <option *ngFor="let locale of this.defservice.createdLocales" [ngValue]="locale">{{this.defservice.localeFormatter(locale)}}</option>
        </select>
    </label>
</div>
```

That options list works fine. When I select different language, model change as a object. To find a FormGroup by locale I create very simple function for that:

```
localizationIndexOf(locale: any): number{
    return (<FormArray>this.form.get('localizationData')).controls.findIndex(x => x.get('locale').value == locale.code);
}
```

And now, the problem what I am challenging is to show user value of FormControl, codelistName, as you can see defined in function addLocalizedFormGroup. Here is html:

```
<ng-container [formGroup]="defservice.form">
    <ng-container formArrayName="localizationData">
        <ng-container [formGroupName]="defservice.localizationIndexOf(defservice.selectedLocale)">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="form-group col-2">
                    <label>Lokalizácia
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" [value]="defservice.localeFormatter(defservice.selectedLocale)"
                                disabled="true">
                    </label>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-10">
                    <label>Názov <span style="color: red">*</span>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="codelistName">
                     </label>
                </div>
            </div>
        </ng-container>
    </ng-container>
</ng-container>
```

But after switch language in option list, localization value change correctly, localizationIndexOf(defservice.selectedLocale) return correct index but after edit codelistName of any index of FormmArray created with function addLocalizedFormGroup, what I added, only first one (with index 0) is changing. I print whole value of form and it show only changed value of first language. Event if I have 2 or 10 languages. I mean 2 or 10 pushed FormGroups into localizationData FormArray of form: FormGroup. It seems like on first load of component, formGroup never update his value, I ref to this line:

```
<ng-container [formGroupName]="defservice.localizationIndexOf(defservice.selectedLocale)">
```

Thank you for any advice.

Comment: Ngmodel and Form control don't mix. https://dev.to/jwp/angular-10-ngmodel-and-formcontrols-e0g

Comment: Ok then, I will change it to form control.

Comment: I am not sure how can be solver this by change it into Form control. Because ngmodel is separated from Form. There are not in same FormGroup or something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recreated the problem on my side but was unable to find a solution with `*ControlName=''` syntax. I found one with `[formControl]=''` but you will have to forget the `formGroupName` hierachy.

If you can keep a reference of the index of the current `FormGroup` of the `localizationData: FormArray`, you will be able to get the control from the array:

```
<input class="..." type="text" [formControl]="localizationData.at(currentLocaleIndex).get('codelistName')">
```

`localizationData` is a getter for the FormArray:

```
get localizationData(): FormArray {
    return this.form.get('localizationData') as FormArray
  }
```

And a solution to keep `currentLocaleIndex` up to date is to update the value when a change happens on the `<select>` like this:

```
<select (change)="updateCurrentLocaleIndex()" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="this.defservice.selectedLocale">
  <option *ngFor="let locale of this.defservice.createdLocales" [ngValue]="locale">{{this.defservice.localeFormatter(locale)}}</option>
</select>
```

In your component  class :

```
updateCurrentLocaleIndex() {
   this.currentLocaleIndex = this.localizationIndexOf(this.defservice.selectedLocale)
 }
```

Comment: Actually I find this solution somewhere but I still waited for solution with ControlName because I like hierarchy with formGroupName. I already implemented this solution 2 days back. But I dont like it. Anyway thank you for your patience and time and help :) have a nice day.

Comment: I understand, let us know when you found it!